# MySql Inner Join throwing an error - Unknown column 'host.hostname' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, join, select, case, inner-join

My table can have different types of output as shown below:

```
hostname    orderId status  Heading         Detail
abc.com     3       30      HeadingA        Details1
abc.com     5       40      HeadingB        Details2
... more rows

hostname    orderId status  Heading         Detail
cde.com     3       40      HeadingA        Details1
cde.com     5       30      HeadingB        Details2
... more rows

hostname    orderId status  Heading         Detail
efg.com     3       50      HeadingA        Details1
efg.com     5       30      HeadingB        Details2
... more rows
```

I want to perform calculation on `status` of first returned row as below:

```
1) If `status is 30` then show status as `Finished`. Also `Heading` and `Detail` should be empty.

2) If `status is 40` or `status is 50` then show status as `Error`. `Heading` and `Detail` should show as such.
```

Desired output is as follows:

```
hostname    orderId status     Heading          Detail
abc.com     3       Finished

hostname    orderId status  Heading         Detail
cde.com     3       Error   HeadingA        Details1

hostname    orderId status  Heading         Detail
efg.com     3       Error   HeadingA        Details1
```

I have written the following query to get desired output:

```
SELECT host.hostname,orderId,
CASE WHEN status = 30 THEN 'Finished' ELSE 'Error' END 'status',
CASE WHEN status = 40 THEN '' ELSE Heading END 'Heading',
CASE WHEN status = 40 THEN '' ELSE Detail END 'Detail'
FROM
(
     SELECT host.hostname,
     cb.orderId,
     cb.status,
     cb.chefbook_name AS Heading,
     (
         SELECT log_message
         FROM   chefbookrun rr
         WHERE  rr.chefbook_id = c.id
         ORDER  BY id DESC 
         LIMIT 1 
     ) AS Detail 
     FROM host
     INNER JOIN host_infl hif ON host.vc_server_id = hif.vc_server_id
     INNER JOIN chefcookbook cb ON hif.id = cb.host_id
     WHERE  host.hostname REGEXP 'abc'
     ORDER  BY cb.orderId
) AS temp
GROUP BY hostname;
```

But it is giving an error:

```
Unknown column 'host.hostname' in 'field list'
```

Please let me know if I need to use `aggregate Group By` in my query because if I remove the query then it is not failing.

```
SELECT temp.hostname,
       orderId,
       CASE WHEN status = 30 THEN 'Finished' ELSE 'Error' END 'status',
       CASE WHEN status = 30 THEN '' ELSE Heading END 'Heading',
       CASE WHEN status = 30 THEN '' ELSE Detail END 'Detail'
FROM(SELECT host.hostname,
            cb.orderId,
            cb.status,
            cb.chefbook_name AS Heading,
            (SELECT log_message
             FROM   chefbookrun rr
             WHERE  rr.chefbook_id = c.id
             ORDER  BY id DESC 
             LIMIT 1 ) AS Detail 
     FROM host
     INNER JOIN host_infl hif ON host.vc_server_id = hif.vc_server_id
     INNER JOIN chefcookbook cb ON hif.id = cb.host_id
     WHERE  host.hostname REGEXP 'abc'
     ORDER  BY cb.orderId
) AS temp;
```

Comment: You don't have a `host.hostname`, because you're selecting from `temp`.in your outermost select.

Comment: @Strawberry In standard SQL & some DBMSs, no aggregations is fine, non-aggregated columns must just be single-valued per group by subrow, according to specified inference rules.

Comment: Please give a [mre]--which includes minimal code & cut & paste & runnable code. But please don't ask duplicate questions. Please summarize research. This is a faq.

Comment: It's not fine. Don't do it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use temp instead of host. Als you dont need GROUP BY clause, since there is no Aggregate clause -

```
SELECT temp.hostname,
       orderId,
       CASE WHEN status = 30 THEN 'Finished' ELSE 'Error' END 'status',
       CASE WHEN status = 30 THEN '' ELSE Heading END 'Heading',
       CASE WHEN status = 30 THEN '' ELSE Detail END 'Detail'
FROM(SELECT host.hostname,
            cb.orderId,
            cb.status,
            cb.chefbook_name AS Heading,
            (SELECT log_message
             FROM   chefbookrun rr
             WHERE  rr.chefbook_id = c.id
             ORDER  BY id DESC 
             LIMIT 1 ) AS Detail 
     FROM host
     INNER JOIN host_infl hif ON host.vc_server_id = hif.vc_server_id
     INNER JOIN chefcookbook cb ON hif.id = cb.host_id
     WHERE  host.hostname REGEXP 'abc'
     ORDER  BY cb.orderId
) AS temp;
```

Comment: This is returning more than one rows for the same host. I need only the topmost row. Should I include `LIMIT 1` in my query?

Comment: Yes, If same host re returning multiple time, You may use LIMIT 1.